# Blazor servisde and 3g, 4g users

Tags: asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I'm developing a web application while using the latest version of .NET, the application is so far built in the MVC due to identity system and many other things, what I'm thinking about is to use Blazor sever side for some parts of it.

The concerns that I have are the following:

- 3g users on their mobile phones. From my own experience, the mobile data is often lost, and the connection with the server might be dropping, this means that users that are using the application via 3g will experience loads of issues?

Is there anything else that I should wonder about?

In the end, should I use it?

Thnx, JS

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider the webassembly flavor. I recommend this spike both versions and test their behaviour. If the interactions though need are slow like button click events you might be able to get away with server side blazor, but I expect the latency to be too large for it.